# How do I know what kind of code fix was given to a specific CVE for Android?

Tags: security, aosp, vulnerability

Consider [CVE-2023-21385](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-21385) which was discovered in AOSP. In this [security bulletin](https://source.android.com/docs/security/bulletin/android-14), they mentioned that this issue was fixed.

Is there any chance to know what kind of fix was given to this CVE (code changes done) that I can take a look at as it is an open-source project?

Comment: The CVE mentions Whitechapel which is a Google chip. So I would start by looking at the Git repo where drivers and services are located that belong to this chip. Unless the CVE is mentioned in the got comment you will have to search for it on your own.

Comment: @Robert I have tried this but this approach takes a lot of brute force searching through the code and PR's. Is there any other optimal way to do this?